# Crystal Report Passing Stored Procedure Parameter from “Like” Sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I have problems in passing stored procedure parameter to crystal report. I tried passing parameter but the result is not like i expected. the parameter can be passed, but the problem is the value of parameter must be exactly the value of parameter. and in my case, i'd like to make the report that can show the report with "like" query, so the parameter can be one, two, or other letter on the real value.

i've tried use the group and record in selection formula, but the result same, the parameter must exactly the value, and cannot just part of letter member of the value.

my table maybe bit like this :

```
employee table
-----------------------
id | name | address   |
01 | Chloe| St. Rose  |
```

my sql maybe a bit like this :

```
    create proc sp_search
    @name varchar(50),
    @address varchar(50)
    as
    select * from employee where name like '%'+@name+'%' 
    and address like '%'+@address+'%'
```

my .net code for passing parameter like :

```
Sub show_search_employee()
    With Me
        Dim report As New employee_report
        report.SetDataSource(ds)
        report.SetParameterValue("@name", name.text) //name parameter
        report.SetParameterValue("@address", address.Text) //address parameter
        form_employee_report.crv_employee.ReportSource = report //set report source
    End With
End Sub
```

my crystal report formula (i just double-click the database field, type '=', and double-click parameter)

`{sp_employee_report;1.name} like {?@name} and`
    `{sp_employee_report;1.address} like {?@address}`

the result can be showed if the name parameter and address parameter exactly the value, like if i'd like to show the '01', i must type the name and address 'Chloe' and 'st. rose'. if i just set the name 'C' or the address 'rose', no value showed. i'd like to set the name parameter just like 'C' or 'Ch' to show the first row, just like the 'Like' function from the sql works. 
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439261/crystal-report-passing-stored-procedure-parameter-from-like-sql

Comment: yes because that's my own question.. i just asked again so anybody can read it again and give me the answer. but finally i got the answer by myself. if you read this question and look for the answer, just check the link that @siva said the duplicate question